# Align items to left in a horizontal layout in Qt

Tags: qt

I have a horizontal layout that contains QLabels. These QLabels are actually icons and I want to left align them in the horizontal layout. The problem is that they are centered no matter what I do. I try to select them all with horizontal left alignment, but they are still centered. I am trying this in Qt Creator under the design page.

Is this expected behavior? Any suggestions on how to get this work?

Comment: I just tried a form layout and it seems I get the result I wanted, but this should be possible to do with a horizontal layout as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add a *horizontal spacer* to the layout. Horizontal spacer is available in the left column of Designer, under "Spacers" section.

Comment: I did not think of using a spacer... It works as expected now. Thank you!